# .htaccess same contents and data are shown repeatedly when naviagted to other pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am new to .htaccess, know nothing about it except that it alters the url.
The following code is from other source (Without 2nd line) and it worked for others.
      What I'm trying to do here is, when i navigate to profile.php from **index.php**:

```html
    <html>
 

    <li><a href="index.php">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $user_data['Username'];?>">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="settings.php">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">Profile</a></li>
    </html>
```

So clearly, i want to pass username as URL to navigate to their profile to display the relative data according to the logged in user. It works fine but if i go back to index.php or some other page it says user doesn't exist.

Here is my profile.php file:

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false)
    {   
    $username = $_GET['username'];
if(user_exists($username) === true)
{
    $user_id = user_id_from_user($username);
    $profile_data = user_data($user_id, 'First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email');    
        else
        {
            echo 'user doesn\'t exist';
        }
      else
        {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
        }
```

?>
//Html section
    First name:
    Last name:
    Email:

Here is my .htaccess code:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*index.php - [L,NS]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Project/profile.php?username=$1

If i remove 2nd line i get an error: (The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request). Actually i tried above code without knowing that i have to set config --- AllowOverride ALL --- after this I'm getting the following errors in log for only this code (i mean only if i remove 2nd line).
Here is my error log for this:

```
[Sun Apr 03 13:27:44.876207 2016] [core:error] [pid 5512:tid 1684] [client ::1:14819] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun Apr 03 13:27:44.876207 2016] [core:error] [pid 5512:tid 1684] [client ::1:14819] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun Apr 03 13:51:23.628421 2016] [core:error] [pid 5512:tid 1684] [client ::1:15004] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun Apr 03 13:51:23.629398 2016] [core:error] [pid 5512:tid 1684] [client ::1:15004] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun Apr 03 13:51:25.422299 2016] [core:error] [pid 5512:tid 1684] [client ::1:15005] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun Apr 03 13:51:25.422299 2016] [core:error] [pid 5512:tid 1684] [client ::1:15005] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Access log:

Normally:

```
::1 - - [04/Apr/2016:03:18:10 +0530] "GET /project/dhanu HTTP/1.1" 200 2573 "http://localhost/project/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
::1 - - [04/Apr/2016:03:18:20 +0530] "GET /project/dhanu HTTP/1.1" 200 2573 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

On removal of .htaccess second line:

```
::1 - - [04/Apr/2016:03:17:58 +0530] "GET /project/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 1060 "http://localhost/project/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
::1 - - [04/Apr/2016:03:17:58 +0530] "GET /project/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 1060 "http://localhost/project/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
::1 - - [04/Apr/2016:03:17:58 +0530] "GET /project/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 1060 "http://localhost/project/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
::1 - - [04/Apr/2016:03:17:58 +0530] "GET /project/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 1060 "http://localhost/project/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
::1 - - [04/Apr/2016:03:18:08 +0530] "GET /project/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1311 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? It looks like you're forcing all traffic to `/Project/profile.php?username=`

Comment: Updated the question clearly. Please read and help.

Comment: Is that .htaccess in the root of your site? What does your site file tree look like? What your .htaccess file right now is doing is rewriting **every** page request to that profile.php URL. Can you show me what your access log looks like?

Comment: Updated. Yes, .htaccess is in root directory (Everything is set properly). I'm trying to rewrite the URL and pass through different parameters. I think that 2nd line of code (got it from some other source) is causing the issue, because the code should work without it but as i said it says (500 internal server error) log file is in question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got to work:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*index\.php$ - [L,NS]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ /project/profile.php?username=$1" [L,NS]
```

index.php

```
<?php
    $user_data = [
        'username' => 'dhanu'
    ];
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $user_data['dhanu'];?>">Profile</a></li>
    </body>
</html>
```

profile.php

```
<?php

// This is where you'd put a database query to check for the user
// this is just a sample that works for your case
function userExists($username) {
    $users = ['thegraz', 'sudi', 'dhanu'];
    return in_array($username, $users);
}

if(isset($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username'] !== '')
{   
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    if (userExists($username))
       echo 'User exists - ' . $username;
    else
        echo 'User doesn\'t exist';
}
```

This way URLs that are just pointing at /project or /project/index.php will just go to index.php.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for still sticking with me. The code is kind of working, first it gave 404 error then i made small changes to work it out. But now if i go to other pages except index.php and profile.php it prints ":user doesn't exist ". I have updated the changes...

Comment: Sorry for the whole mess, I hope you know what I'm trying to do here. Assume that I'm kind of developing a website like facebook, where i want to display the details of the users who has logged in with .htaccess file. I don't have a clue about what's happening here. Please help me out. I have searched everywhere but dint find anything helpful...